# Updating my newly built homes address on Google maps

Tags: google-maps

I have been reporting this issue for months on Google maps and have gotten no where.

I would like to speak to an actual human about my issue.

It's almost been a year since we moved into our new house and Google maps still has not updated to reflect my correct location.  We are unable to use our address in GPS to get anyone to find our new house.

Comment: StackOverflow has no connection to Google

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about contacting Google, not coding

Comment: Google maps sent me here for my issue when I was reporting it.

Comment: They must in some fashion because I was directly linked here from Google maps.

Comment: For **technical questions**

Comment: Does this answer your doubt?  https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6320846?hl=en&ref_topic=3257381

Comment: Those options are for adding business locations.  Not for residential edits/updates. :( ty tho for the link

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with software development whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow instructions from this KB : https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6320846

Until March 2017 you can also use mapmaker.google.com to add residential addresses ([retirement notice](https://support.google.com/mapmaker/answer/7195127?visit_id=1-636223366727229845-1754842399&p=graduation&rd=1)):

1) Go to https://mapmaker.google.com/mapmaker?hl=en

2) Select "Add New"

3) Select "Add a place"

4) Drop the pin in the location of the new addition you are adding

5) Select 'address' for category (this is the category for residences)

6) Enter the additional information for the residence and click save

There is also an article here:

https://support.google.com/mapmaker/answer/1731390?hl=en

I hope this helps!